# A proof of the continuity of measure.

Tags: measure-theory

We know that Lebesgue measure is continuous, which states that if $A_1\subseteq A_2\subseteq A_3\subseteq\dots $, then $m^*(\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^\infty A_k)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} A_n$.

Why doesn't the following proof work?

For any $k\in\Bbb{N}$, $\bigcup\limits_{j=1}^k A_j=A_k$. Hence, $m^*(\bigcup\limits_{j=1}^k A_j)=m^*(A_k)$.

We hence have two sequence, composed of positive real numbers, both of which are exactly the same. Hence, as this is a monotone sequence, the limits of both must exist, and be the same too. Hence, $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}m^*(\bigcup\limits_{j=1}^k A_j)=\lim\limits_{k\to\infty} m^*(A_k)$. This implies $m^*(\bigcup\limits_{j=1}^\infty A_j)=\lim\limits_{k\to\infty} m^*(A_k)$.

Why is this proof incorrect? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You seem to be assuming that $$\lim_{k\to\infty} m^{*}\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^{k}A_j\right) = m^{*}\left( \bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}A_j\right)$$ which is a form of what you are trying to prove.

Comment: The last sentence: "This implies". Why? Why should the limit of the measures have anything to do with the measure of the union?

Comment: May i know, how you show that Lebesgue measure is continuous?

Comment: I know this, I asked it to answer Ayush Khaitan' question. he has  used the things that is Precisely going to prove it.