# If something is true for every $n\in\Bbb{N}$, does it imply that thing is true for $\infty$?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I have the following expression

> $m(\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^\infty E_i)\geq \sum\limits_{i=1}^n m(E_i)$.
>
> **Since the left side of the inequality is independent of $n$**, we have $m(\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^\infty E_i)\geq \sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty m(E_i)$

I don't understand this argument. Is $\infty$ a natural number? If something is true for every natural number, how does it prove that it is true for $\infty$? Is there some kind of limiting process happening here?

Comment: The answer to the question in the title is embedded within the question itself, since $\infty\not\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer your question, but the limit exists because the real-valued sequence $a_n = \sum_i^n m(E_i)$ is monotone and bounded above.

Comment: I've posted an answer below with an $\text{“}\varepsilon\text{-}N\text{''}$ proof that the proposed inference is right.  It seems to me that the other answers lean toward mere _assertions_ that it's right. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 3):

Take the limit of both sides as $n\to\infty$. On the left-hand side, nothing happens, as $n$ does not appear. On the right-hand side, we get exactly $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}m(E_i)$.

Comment: That exactly is my bone of contention. Is $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n m(E_i)$ equal to $\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty m(E_i)$? Because that would be very weird

Comment: @AyushKhaitan Yes, actually this limit you write is the *definition* of the infinite sum.

Comment: @AyushKhaitan Yes, by definition that's what the infinite sum means.

Comment: That is the definition of $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}m(E_i)$: as the limit of the sequence of partial sums. Although you do need to know the limit exists.

Comment: Wow, that's some simultaneity right there. :P @AyushKhaitan On an intuitive level, I'm curious; why do you find this definition weird?

Comment: @Did- Can we also say that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^n A_k=\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^\infty A_k$?

Comment: @Did- Because that would contradict a stackexchange answer I got today

Comment: How do you define a limit of sets?

Comment: @AyushKhaitan There you have to be a little more careful, since a "limit of sets" may not be particularly well-defined.

Comment: @Andrew- What about $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}m^*(\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^n A_k)=m^*(\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^\infty A_k)$? Considering $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^n A_k=\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^\infty A_k$?

Comment: @AyushKhaitan if you're referring to the comments on your question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1446761/a-proof-of-the-continuity-of-measure, there's no contradiction: there you are talking about measures of infinite unions, not infinite sums of real numbers.

Answer (score 2):

You're right, it's not that simple. But it's pretty close: by definition, the infinite sum $S_\infty=\sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i$ is the limit of $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^nx_i$. If each $S_n$ is less than some fixed value $a$, then certainly the limit of the $S_n$ cannot be bigger than $a$.

Comment: It should be added that the definition of the infinite union is ***not*** a limit. So computing the measure of that union is "one clock cycle", not a limit process of infinitely many "clock cycles".

Comment: @AsafKaragila That's a good point, although you *can* define it that way if you really want, and it's sometimes useful to think this way in computability theory.

Answer (score 2):

For each $n\in\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}$, every set of size $n$ is finite.  Therefore every set of size $\infty$ is finite.

Most certainly it is **not** true that if something is true for every $n\in\mathbb N$, it is true of $\infty$.  The intersection of any finite number of open sets is open; the intersection of infinitely many open sets is usually not open.

Recall that $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^\infty m(E_k)$ is defined as $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^n m(E_k)$.  So the question comes to this:
$$
\text{If }A \ge B_n\text{ for all $n$, does it follow that }A\ge\lim_{n\to\infty} B_n\text{?}
$$
Assuming the latter limit exists, the only alternative is
$$
A < \lim_{n\to\infty} B_n = L.
$$
Assuming that alternative, let $\varepsilon = \lim_{n\to\infty} B_n - A > 0$.  By the $\text{“}\varepsilon$-$N\text{''}$ definition of the limit of a sequence, there exists $N$ so large that for all $n\ge N$, $B_n>L-\varepsilon$. That implies $B_n>A$, contradicting the hypothesis.

**Postscript 23 hours later:**

**Right:** If $A\ge B_n$ for all $n$, then $A\ge \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} B_n$.

**Wrong:** If $A > B_n$ for all $n$, then $A > \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} B_n$.

The fact that the second statement is *wrong* is another instance of the fact that you *cannot* say that if something is true of every $n\in\mathbb N$, then it is true of $\infty$.